# "Mic lock" button is disabled | lenovo x280

Tags: lenovo-laptop

"Mute Microphone" button, does not work.  In "lenovo thinkpad x280

Of course I tried to update drivers, as well as download all Windows updates.

Windows 11 operating system

Comment: See [this page](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-IdeaPad-1xx-3xx-5xx-7xx-Edge-LaVie-Z-Flex-Notebooks/F4-Microphone-BUTTON-stopped-working/m-p/5029690?page=6).

Comment: All the solutions offered there are for Windows 10. Of course, I say this after having studied the multitude of solutions offered there.

Comment: Which OS you're running, hardware specifications and what you tried and the results should be in the question from the start. It's your job when asking to present all the relevant info, it's not our job to guess or even google your laptop's model.

Comment: Can you mute the mic in the software? Is it just the physical mute button or hotkey that isn't working?

Comment: The hotkey didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by installing a driver that is compatible with Windows 10, then downloading drivers that fit the device via the company's website